# mysql query to select user count with Like clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a forum, there's an option for user to change their names. Also i have staff members with names  like `[ADM]James`. I want to prevent users to change his name in James.

Example: I have a memeber from staff with name `[ADM]James`, users should not be able to change his name in simply James.

There's my query :  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name='James' LIKE '[%%'` However this query return strange numbers it always return whole count of users.

What i do wrong?

EDIT, WHAT IS UNCLEAR?

I have 2 staff members. Admins and moderators, admins have tag name [ADM] moderators [MOD].  Example two names: [ADM]James  [MOD]Jeff .. When a user try to change his name in James count should return 1. Because there is already one staff memeber with name [ADM]James.

```
CREATE TABLE `user`  (
  `id` int(0) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONAME',
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 191782 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

Comment: `where name like '%James'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%]%'

SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%[ADM]%' group by user;
```

Comment: It's same, it return all users from table.

Comment: You want only James?

Comment: Read again my question :D

Comment: Your question in not clear. Or provide your sample data and desired result

Comment: I have 2 staff members.  Admins / monderators..  Admins have tag [ADM], moderators have tag [MOD[..   If i have an admin named  [ADM]James,  when a forum user with name  Jeffery, he should not be able to change name in  James. Because is already used by [ADM]James.  I want the count of users with [ADM]James, if there is a single staff member with name [ADM]James, count should return 1,

Comment: can you provide the columns you have in the table. I got your requirement, trying to provide you proper query

Comment: I added table structure in first post

Comment: SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%[ADM]%' group by user;  -- Is this what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%James%'
```

Will count every name that has 'James' on it.

`WHERE name='James' LIKE '[%%'` is not a valid where clause

The syntax of the [LIKE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) is `expr LIKE pat [ESCAPE 'escape_char']`
You can either use `%` or `_`

- `%` matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
- `_` matches exactly one character.

Comment: I want if there exist a name ]James to not be able to change name

Comment: Then you can search for `WHERE name LIKE '%]James%'` of if you want to avoid brackets `WHERE name LIKE '%]%'`

Comment: It's same, it return all users from table.

Comment: If all your users have ']' in their names, yes, it returns all of them. You want to filter for [ADM] and [MOD] maybe? Then `WHERE name LIKE '%[MOD]%' OR name LIKE '%[ADM]%'` will have count > 0 if your new user is trying to have one of the name already used by your admins/mods